# mysql replication - slave can't connect to master

Tags: mysql, replication

mysql 5.7.18 (both master and slave)

## error in slave status

```
Last_IO_Error: Master command COM_REGISTER_SLAVE failed: Access denied for user 'repl'@'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' (using password: YES) (Errno: 1045)
```

## error on master (error.log)

```
2017-05-29T16:40:39.718290Z 213 [Note] Aborted connection 213 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'repl' host: 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' (Got an error reading communication packets)
```

## connecting from slave to master via mysql client

But if I login from the slave servers command line like this there is no error and the slave connects to the master perfectly. So there must be something in the master-slave configuration thats not right

```
mysql -h xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -u repl -pxxxxxxxxxxxx
mysql> show grants;
+--------------------------------------------+
| Grants for repl@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx            |
+--------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'repl'@'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' |
+--------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

## create replication user on master

```
CREATE USER 'repl'@'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' IDENTIFIED BY 'xxxxx';
GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO 'repl'@'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

## master my.cnf

```
[mysqld]

# GENERAL #
user                           = mysql
port                           = 3306
default_storage_engine         = InnoDB
pid-file                       = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket                         = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

# SAFETY #
max_allowed_packet             = 16M
max_connect_errors             = 1000000
skip_name_resolve
sql_mode                       = STRICT_ALL_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,NO_ZERO_DATE,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO
sysdate_is_now                 = 1
symbolic_links                 = 0

# DATA STORAGE #
datadir                        = /var/lib/mysql/

# BINARY LOGGING #
server_id                      = 1
log_bin                        = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin
log_slave_updates
expire_logs_days               = 14
sync_binlog                    = 1
log_bin_trust_function_creators= 1
binlog_format                  = ROW

# REPLICATION #
gtid_mode                      = ON
enforce_gtid_consistency

# CACHES AND LIMITS #
tmp_table_size                 = 64M
max_heap_table_size            = 64M
query_cache_type               = 0
query_cache_size               = 0
max_connections                = 500
thread_cache_size              = 50
open_files_limit               = 65535
table_definition_cache         = 4096
table_open_cache               = 4096
wait_timeout                   = 60

# INNODB #
innodb_flush_method                 = O_DIRECT
innodb_log_files_in_group           = 2
innodb_log_file_size                = 512M
innodb_log_buffer_size              = 64M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit      = 1
innodb_file_per_table               = 1
innodb_buffer_pool_size             = 40G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances        = 12
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode            = 2
innodb_adaptive_hash_index          = 0
innodb_change_buffering             = none

# LOGGING #
log_error                      = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-error.log
log_queries_not_using_indexes  = 1
slow_query_log                 = 1
slow_query_log_file            = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-slow.log
long_query_time                = 1

basedir                        = /usr
tmpdir                         = /tmp
lc_messages_dir                = /usr/share/mysql
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp
```

## slave my.cnf

```
[mysqld]

# GENERAL #
user                           = mysql
port                           = 3306
default_storage_engine         = InnoDB
pid-file                       = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket                         = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

# SAFETY #
max_allowed_packet             = 16M
max_connect_errors             = 1000000
skip_name_resolve
sql_mode                       = STRICT_ALL_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,NO_ZERO_DATE,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO
sysdate_is_now                 = 1
symbolic_links                 = 0

# DATA STORAGE #
datadir                        = /var/lib/mysql/

# BINARY LOGGING #
server_id                      = 2
log_bin                        = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin
log_slave_updates
expire_logs_days               = 14
sync_binlog                    = 1
log_bin_trust_function_creators= 1
binlog_format                  = ROW

# REPLICATION #
gtid_mode                      = ON
enforce_gtid_consistency

# CACHES AND LIMITS #
tmp_table_size                 = 64M
max_heap_table_size            = 64M
query_cache_type               = 0
query_cache_size               = 0
max_connections                = 500
thread_cache_size              = 50
open_files_limit               = 65535
table_definition_cache         = 4096
table_open_cache               = 4096
wait_timeout                   = 60

# INNODB #
innodb_flush_method                 = O_DIRECT
innodb_log_files_in_group           = 2
innodb_log_file_size                = 512M
innodb_log_buffer_size              = 64M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit      = 1
innodb_file_per_table               = 1
innodb_buffer_pool_size             = 12G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances        = 8
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode            = 2
innodb_adaptive_hash_index          = 0
innodb_change_buffering             = none

# LOGGING #
log_error                      = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-error.log
log_queries_not_using_indexes  = 1
slow_query_log                 = 1
slow_query_log_file            = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-slow.log
long_query_time                = 1

basedir                        = /usr
tmpdir                         = /tmp
lc_messages_dir                = /usr/share/mysql
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp
```

## master status

```
show master status\G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
             File: mysql-bin.000005
         Position: 194
     Binlog_Do_DB:
 Binlog_Ignore_DB:
Executed_Gtid_Set: e4e90c71-4264-11e7-b970-4061862b8d34:1-12803
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

## slave status

```
show slave status\G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Waiting to reconnect after a failed registration on master
                  Master_Host: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
                  Master_User: repl
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File:
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 4
               Relay_Log_File: Worker-Intel-i7-2600-16gb-relay-bin.000001
                Relay_Log_Pos: 4
        Relay_Master_Log_File:
             Slave_IO_Running: Connecting
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
          Replicate_Ignore_DB:
           Replicate_Do_Table:
       Replicate_Ignore_Table:
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table:
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table:
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error:
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 0
              Relay_Log_Space: 154
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File:
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File:
           Master_SSL_CA_Path:
              Master_SSL_Cert:
            Master_SSL_Cipher:
               Master_SSL_Key:
        Seconds_Behind_Master: 0
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 1130
                Last_IO_Error: Master command COM_REGISTER_SLAVE failed: Access denied for user 'repl'@'176.9.137.3' (using password: YES) (Errno: 1045)
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error:
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids:
             Master_Server_Id: 0
                  Master_UUID:
             Master_Info_File: /var/lib/mysql/master.info
                    SQL_Delay: 0
          SQL_Remaining_Delay: NULL
      Slave_SQL_Running_State: Slave has read all relay log; waiting for more updates
           Master_Retry_Count: 86400
                  Master_Bind:
      Last_IO_Error_Timestamp: 170529 17:24:04
     Last_SQL_Error_Timestamp:
               Master_SSL_Crl:
           Master_SSL_Crlpath:
           Retrieved_Gtid_Set:
            Executed_Gtid_Set: 8976078a-40a0-11e7-8043-c8600054b161:1-1085
                Auto_Position: 1
         Replicate_Rewrite_DB:
                 Channel_Name:
           Master_TLS_Version:
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

## start/setup slave

```
# mysql -u root -pxxxxxxxxxxx
# stop slave;
# CHANGE MASTER TO 
# MASTER_HOST = 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx',
# MASTER_PORT = 3306,
# MASTER_USER = 'repl',
# MASTER_PASSWORD = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
# MASTER_AUTO_POSITION = 1;
# start slave;
# show slave status\G;
```

Comment: Have you opened the firewall ports?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: The servers are located at hetzner so that should not be needed

Comment: What does the GRANT for `repl` look like?  Did the IP address change?

Comment: Its stated in the bottom of the question.. have updated the question.. If I try to connect to the master from the slave with the `repl` user I get no errors...

Comment: @RickJames the IP adresses are the same in both create user and grant

Comment: When I had this issue, it was solved (??? or hacked) by putting this line in the config file   `bind-address = 0.0.0.0`

Comment: @AllenKing still same error

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Clark you mentioned **USAGE** only as the grants applied you also need **REPLICATION SLAVE**.

```
mysql> show grants;
+--------------------------------------------+
| Grants for repl@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx            |
+--------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'repl'@'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' |
+--------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

If usage means you can only connect to the DB Server and not anything else. Whereas in this case REPLICATION SLAVE will require to read and pull binlog events from Master.

***To Fix this:***

***On Master Execute:***

> ```
> GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO 'repl'@'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' identified by 'xxxxx';
>
> flush privileges;
> ```

[difference this time is you are granting with the password for REPLICATION SLAVE GRANT]

***Show Grants:***

If you do show grants; after you give GRANT REPLICATION command. You should get below grants from same slave host via CLI.

```
mysql> show grants;
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for repl@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx                                                              |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO repl@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD <secret> |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.03 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: I already have run this `CREATE USER 'repl'@'176.9.xxx.xxx' IDENTIFIED BY 'slave_pass'; GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO 'repl'@'176.9.xxx.xxx';` on master

Comment: but I don't see that in show grants. can you execute GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO 'repl'@'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' identified by 'xxxxx';   and let me know about show grants   ?

Comment: strange now I get `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' ` when trying to execute the statement from `root` user.. When I look into `mysql.user` all columns is set to `Y` on `root`

Comment: have also tried to `service mysql restart` but still get the error when trying to grant privileges to `repl` from `root`

Comment: So you mean to say you can't login to master as root which you were able to before?

Comment: yes.. I cant grant anything from `root` anymore.. `show grants` => `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' ` (with grant option is missing even if it is set to Y in mysql.user)

Comment: follow this method https://www.howtoforge.com/setting-changing-resetting-mysql-root-passwords and recover mysql root password  see section under Recover MySQL root password

Comment: Thanks, this has worked for me. But this grant can be lost without reasons? or maybe someone has revoked this grant? my replication was fine and so, I got this erro.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like a password issue. 1045
Does your password have the # character? remove it
Is your password longer than 32 characters? shorten it

See [TROUBLESHOOTING MYSQL REPLICATION ERROR 1045](https://web.archive.org/web/20170526205802/https://nerdherd.com/archives/524)

Comment: This was a vicious gotcha. Replication slave passwords can't be more than 32 characters? Thanks, MySQL!

Answer (score 2):

***This is not the correct solution to the problem*** (the error code is really different), but I'll leave it, as I wasted lot of time searching for a solution to this problem. The answer might be useful to somebody after all.

---

I had similar case with error in the slave log file

```
error connecting to master '...' - retry-time: 60  retries: 12, Error_code: 3159
```

The problem was that the master required secure connection. Starting the slave with

```
Master_SSL_Allowed  Yes
```

Fixed my problems

Comment: This is a different error code. I don't think this is a valid answer in response to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Glad previous answer was not deleted, it pointed me in the right direction. I have a master-master environment set up in VirtualBox with SSL enabled. At master1 when I ran CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST, I did not set MASTER_SSL=1. However, replication was working. At master2 I was getting the following err msg. After RESET SLAVE, I ran the CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST with the correct parameters on both masters to fix the issue.

```
Slave_IO_Running: Connecting
Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
Last_IO_Errno: 2026
Last_IO_Error: error connecting to master 'xxx@xxx.xxx.x.xxx:3306' - retry-time: 60  retries: 1

CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', MASTER_USER='RepAcc', MASTER_PASSWORD='***', MASTER_LOG_FILE='mysql-bin.000001', MASTER_LOG_POS=154, MASTER_SSL=1, MASTER_SSL_CA='/path/to/ca-cert.pem', MASTER_SSL_CERT = '/path/to/master-public.pem', MASTER_SSL_KEY = '/path/to/master-private.pem';
```

Answer (score 0):

mysql version > 8.0

if you are creating user mode:

`create user 'repl'@'%' identified by '123456'`

the sign method is: `caching_sha2_password`,we need add options `GET_MASTER_PUBLIC_KEY=1` to the `CHANGE MASTER TO`

use:

```
CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='master_ip',MASTER_PORT=3306, MASTER_USER='RepAcc', MASTER_PASSWORD='***', MASTER_LOG_FILE='mysql-bin.000001', MASTER_LOG_POS=154,GET_MASTER_PUBLIC_KEY=1;
```

it work!

or

if you are creating user mode:
`create user 'repl'@'%' identified with mysql_native_password by '123456'`;

use:

```
CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='master_ip',MASTER_PORT=3306, MASTER_USER='repl', MASTER_PASSWORD='***', MASTER_LOG_FILE='mysql-bin.000001', MASTER_LOG_POS=154;
```

it work also！

last exec:

`show slave status \G;`: